# Select array of string MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Hello I have a couple row that look like this:

```
{
     name:"row1",
     industry_name:["ind1", "ind2"],
     ... (other fields)
},
{
     name:"row2",
     industry_name:["ind1", "ind3"]
     ... (other fields)
}
```

And I want to select all rows, and just return the name and the list of industry names, so here is what I have:

```
 db.Companies.find({"name":{$exists:true}}, {_id:0, name:1, industry_name:1})
```

But this returns:

```
{ "name" : "row1" }
{ "name" : "row2" }
```

No industry names are returned. How can I also get the list of industries?

Thank you

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which versions of db and client you are using?

Comment: @AlexBlex I have mongodb 3.2.12 installed on a linux machine where I am runnign that command

Comment: Then it is either a typo in the field name, or you have other documents that match the condition, but don't have `industry_name`. Just to double check, you are running commands in the mongo shell, which is v3.2.12 as well, right? Try to set `_id:1` in projection to confirm documents are the ones you expect. Also, try `findOne()` to copy-paste `industry_name` from the document into the query projection.